# regular expression matching a 3 or 4 digit cvv of a credit card

Tags: regex

I really don't know regexp yet, but sooner or later I will read and learn. 
But for now I need a regular expression matching a 3 or 4 digit cvv of a credit card so I can validate the input in javascript and later in PHP.
cvv are supposed to be 3 or 4 digit as far as I know.

I tried this in my javascript code and I am not sure if it is correct.

```
if (/[0-9]{3}+/.test(value))
return false;
```

Comment: `if ((parseint(value) >= 100) || (parseInt(value) <= 9999))` is much easier than an expensive regex to force everything into a 3-4digit range.

Comment: @Marc B: That doesn't quite do the same. If the code begins with a zero (such as "042") then it can be three digits, but still fail your test because the numeric value is below 100.

Comment: exactly, that's why I needed a regexp here. Because 001 < 100 and a 001 is a vaid cvv but still fails the (parseint(value) >= 100. I tried that @Marc B

Comment: @mark: true enough. serves the CC companies right for allowing left-0 padded digits. Obviously they should change the global payment system to disallow this :)

Comment: lol, so true @Marc B. It could have to do with the old tape reader that expected 3 holes, and now they made so much money they don't care anymore. Or maybe they don't really use the brains anymore. Again great quote.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

To match 3 or 4 digits, use the following regular expression:

```
/^[0-9]{3,4}$/
```

Explanation:

- `^`: Start of string anchor
- `[0-9]`: Digit between 0 and 9 (you could also use `\d` here)
- `{3,4}`: A quantifier meaning between 3 and 4.
- `$`: End of string anchor

Comment: So every regexp starts with /^ and finishes with $/ and in between I put my patterns.. I can also start another expression after $/ ? or it is always the end?

Comment: @themhz: The `/` marks the start and end of the regular expression. `^` and `$` are anchors. They are optional, but you need them here otherwise your regular expression won't do what you want.

Comment: for anyone reading this that doesn't know - AMEX (American Express) cards have 4 digit CVV codes and Visa and Mastercard are 3 digits