# How can I efficiently rewrite a regex pattern to find three or more digit groupings?

Tags: python, regex

I need to write a regex pattern to identify a three or four digit number, followed by a plus symbol, followed by another three or four digit number.

```
cell1 = "$800 + AXL $200"
cell2 = "USD1000+USD2000 no refund, expires Jan 20 2022"
pattern_three_digits = r"\W*\w*(\d{3,})\s*(\+)\s*\w*\s*\W*(\d{3,})"
pattern_four_digits = r"\W*\w*(\d{4,})\s*(\+)\s*\w*\s*\W*(\d{4,})"
```

This is so I can sum the two groups of numbers like so:

```
z = re.match(pattern_four_digits, cell2)
if z.group(2)=="+":
    sum = int(z.group(1)) + int(z.group(3))
    print(sum)
```

The output for this is fine and expected: "3000"

The problem is that I needed to write a separate `pattern_four_digits` because `pattern_three_digits` will only recognize three of the zeroes in variable `cell2`.

How can I rewrite my pattern so that it can match a combination of three and four digit groupings? I'll likely have other another cell like `$3000 + sometext $200`.

Can I have my cake and eat it too? Or do I need to write multiple patterns for the various edge cases?

To be clear, I want the pattern to succeed in these cases:

```
cell1 = "$800 + AXL $200"
cell2 = "USD1000+USD2000 no refund, expires Jan 20 2022"
cell3 = "$3000 + sometext $200"
cell4 = "$200 + sometext $3000"
```

edit: I couldn't get the [popular solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12011792/regular-expression-matching-a-3-or-4-digit-cvv-of-a-credit-card) to work so any help is appreciated.

I figured it out: `r"\D*(\d{3,5})\D*(\+)\D*(\d{3,5})"` is the pattern I want.

Comment: In your own words, when you write `\d{3,}`, why do you think you need the comma? What do you think that indicates, syntax-wise? Now, what does the documentation say? Do you see how you can use that information to specify a sequence of either 3 or 4 digits?

Comment: Please explicitly highlight all the test cases the regex should succeed in.

Comment: I found the linked duplicate by putting `regex three or four digits` [into a search engine](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=regex+three+or+four+digits), as the first result. It really is that easy. Please try at least this much in the future. It [is expected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Well I assumed the comma followed by the closing bracket indicates an infinite upper bound which seems to be the case in the documentation. Interestingly, the documentation says "on the 6-character string 'aaaaaa', a{3,5} will match 5 'a' characters." I tried {3,5} since the 5 is exclusive but I'm still only getting three zeroes. It omits the leading digit. What am I missing here?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel The top answer for the first result "/^[0-9]{3,4}$/" doesn't work when I substitute that fragment into my larger pattern and I'm not sure why. But rather than write a question about someone else's code that doesn't work, I posted code I actually wrote myself and asked for improvement.  I've been using SO heavily on this project so researching before asking a question isn't lost on me.

Comment: Can you verify that that part of the pattern does what you expect it to *in isolation*? Good; now you have a new question that is better posed for the site. Try to add parts to the regex and make sure they do what you expect, [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) along the way.

Comment: I figured it out: `r"\D*(\d{3,5})\D*(\+)\D*(\d{3,5})"` is the pattern I'm looking for.